# String comparision in if statement generates some warnings

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a calculator, but my `if` statement generates some warnings. I am also new to C.

```
int main(){

    float num1;
    float num2;

    char input[5];

    printf("Hello my name is baymax\n");
    printf("Enter either add, sub, mult, div:\n");
    scanf("%4s", input);

    printf("Enter first number\n");
    scanf("%f", &num1);

    printf("Enter second number\n");
    scanf("%f", &num2);

    if(input == 'add'){
        printf("%.1f + %.1f = %.1f",num1, num2, num1+num2);
    ....
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the string entered is `add`, it should add the two numbers. But I get the following warnings when compiling:

```
calculator.c:19:14: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
        if(input == 'add'){
                    ^
calculator.c:19:11: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
      ('char *' and 'int')
        if(input == 'add'){
```

Comment: When you ask question that deals with warnings, always include warning in the question as a text (not as a image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *two* problems with that code: The first is that `'add'` is a multi-character literal, and not a string. A string would use double-quotes like `"add"`.

The second problem is that you can't use equality comparison to compare string, as that will compare the *pointers* and not the contents of the strings. To compare strings you need to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

```
if (strcmp(input, "add") == 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `strcmp` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) is your friend

You need

```
if (strcmp(input, "add") == 0) ...
```

PS: Look up the manual page for `scanf` - It does return a value that you should check

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this is the line that warns you

```
if(input == 'add')
```

In C strings are a derived type, not a native type as `int`, `float`, `char`, etc, so you cannot use them directly.
You have to use a function to compare strings. There are many functions that works on string in the standard library (defined in `string.h`). They all start with `str` prefix (well almost all, see manuals).
In your specific case you need `strcmp()` to compare strings, that will return 0 if they are equal:

```
if(strcmp(input, "add") == 0)
```

Comment: `strcmp` is from `string.h`, not `stdio.h`